# Parsing json with php error "invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Tags: php, json

I have a problem with parsing a json feed with php and can not figure out what I am doing wrong.

**JSON feed**

```
[{"id":10428167,"url":"some_url","amount":1197,"price":0.37,"seller":{"id":4682621,"name":"Rap17ka7a"}},
{"id":10428466,"url":"some_url","amount":1450,"price":0.37,"seller":{"id":5031734,"name":"Meanor"}},
{"id":10429969,"url":"some_url","amount":109,"price":0.37,"seller":{"id":5862543,"name":"djeisanborn"}}]
```

**PHP parser**

```
$request_url ="json_feed_url_is_here";
$requests = file_get_contents($request_url);
$response = json_decode($requests);
foreach ($response as $item) {
$seller = $item->seller->name;

$seller = str_replace("'", "&#39;", $seller);
$seller = str_replace("’", "&rsquo;;", $seller);


$sql = ("INSERT INTO table_name ( ~~~cell names~~~) 
        VALUES (~~~cell values~~~, '$item->amount', '$item->price', '$item->url')") or  die('<b>Data Insert Error:</b> ' . mysql_error());
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con1))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
}
```

**What I get is this error:**

```
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in path_to_php_file
```

Comment: `Var_dump` the result for debugging. Show a hex excerpt of the file start.

Comment: Your php [seems ok](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ctEXZD), `var_dump` the `$requests`.

Comment: `var_dump($requests);` gives normal data output

Answer (score 6):

Set the second argument of [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) to `true` to convert the JSON to associative array instead of object.

```
$response = json_decode($requests, true);
```

Comment: it is already an array, because it is wrapped by `[]`. I confirm this by running the code.

Comment: @ariefbayu you're right, the result is an array of object. The original code should be ok.

Comment: @milenmk check if the JSON only contains a single element so its not wrapped in `[]`. e.g: `{"id":10428167,"url":"some_url","amount":1197,"price":0.37,"seller":{"id":4682621,"name":"Rap17ka7a"}`.

Comment: @bsdnoobz, all 10 elements are inside the []